# SQL ADD Constraint rule to employees about gender (M,F)

Tags: sql

I want to write an SQL query where a constraint rule is assigned to employees about gender.

i tried to do it but i keep getting an error.

I have a Table named employees and there i have the gender and i want to apply a constraint rule that employees only can get M or F. so its 1 varchar.

can someone help me please.

```
my Error:
postgres.public> ALTER TABLE medewerkers ADD CONSTRAINT m_geslacht_chk
                     CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(COL, '^[MF]*$'))
[2021-09-13 21:08:16] [42P01] ERROR: relation "medewerkers" does not exist
```

my code:

```
ALTER TABLE medewerkers ADD CONSTRAINT m_geslacht_chk CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(geslacht, '^[MF]*$'));

CREATE TABLE medewerkers
(
    mnr      NUMERIC(4)     CONSTRAINT m_pk         PRIMARY KEY
                            CONSTRAINT m_mnr_chk    CHECK (mnr > 7000),
    naam     VARCHAR(12)    CONSTRAINT m_naam_nn    NOT NULL,
    voorl    VARCHAR(5)     CONSTRAINT m_voorl_nn   NOT NULL,
    functie  VARCHAR(10),
    chef     NUMERIC(4)     CONSTRAINT m_chef_fk    REFERENCES medewerkers DEFERRABLE,
    gbdatum  DATE           CONSTRAINT m_gebdat_nn  NOT NULL,
    maandsal NUMERIC(6, 2)  CONSTRAINT m_mndsal_nn  NOT NULL,
    comm     NUMERIC(6, 2),
    afd      NUMERIC(2)     DEFAULT 10,
    geslacht VARCHAR(2)     CONSTRAINT m_geslacht_chk NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You have to CREATE the table _before_ you can ADD constraints to it.

Comment: The table is already created.

Comment: It is? According to your code you do ALTER TABLE _before_ CREATE TABLE. Can you do `select * from medewerkers`?

Comment: yes i can do that

Comment: i putted the code below the query statement but i cant execute it

Comment: No need for a Postgresql `REGEXP_LIKE`, keep it simple - `CHECK (geslacht IN ('M', 'F'))`!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the CREATE TABLE in such a way that the named constraint is part of the table definition (solving the point  mentioned by @jarlh)

PostgreSQL does not support `REGEXP_LIKE`, instead `SIMILAR TO` should be used.

Source:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP

```
CREATE TABLE medewerkers
(
    mnr      NUMERIC(4)      CONSTRAINT m_pk         PRIMARY KEY
                             CONSTRAINT m_mnr_chk    CHECK (mnr > 7000),
    naam     VARCHAR(12)     CONSTRAINT m_naam_nn    NOT NULL,
    voorl    VARCHAR(5)      CONSTRAINT m_voorl_nn   NOT NULL,
    functie  VARCHAR(10),
    chef     NUMERIC(4)      CONSTRAINT m_chef_fk    REFERENCES medewerkers DEFERRABLE,
    gbdatum  DATE            CONSTRAINT m_gebdat_nn  NOT NULL,
    maandsal NUMERIC(6, 2)   CONSTRAINT m_mndsal_nn  NOT NULL,
    comm     NUMERIC(6, 2),
    afd      NUMERIC(2)      DEFAULT 10,
    geslacht VARCHAR(2)      CONSTRAINT m_geslacht_chk check (geslacht SIMILAR TO '^[MF]*$') NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: if i do that the code ```REGEXP_LIKE``` becomes red and i cant execute it. im stuck i dont know what to do

Comment: @klaasvanburen10, I updated the check with SIMILAR TO, that is the way to perform regex comparison in postgres (I verified on my own test db)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE medewerkers
    ADD geslacht VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT m_geslacht_chk CHECK (geslacht in ('M', 'F', 'N'));
```

This worked

Comment: This may in fact be better, since the method using `SIMILAR TO` allows for zero or more gender characters, limited to 2 characters due to `VARCHAR(2)`

Comment: Thanks for remembering me that i did not change ```VARCHAR(2)``` to ```VARCHAR(1)```